# cmd batch to merge text files based on filename to seperate txt files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, merge

I have a folder which contains 10000 text files. something like this:

```
the end 1.txt
the end 2.txt
the end 3.txt
the blue one 1.txt
the blue one 2.txt
the blue one 3.txt
the blue one 4.txt
first letter 1.txt
first letter 2.txt
first letter 3.txt
```

I want each set of text files (that have the same name) to be merged to one single text file. something like this
- the blue one all.txt
- first letter all.txt
- the end all.txt

I know I can merge text files using commnad:
copy *.txt allfiles.txt
I need to merge them based on part of their name.

Comment: I commend your attention to [SS64 on `COPY`](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html).

Comment: None of the files in your question have the same name!!! I'm guessing you're wanting to filter only on part names, but you don't explain which parts: `the blue one`, `the blue`, `blue one`, `the`, `blue`, or `one`; and likewise, `first letter`, `first`, `letter` or in fact whether those are case sensitive, whole words only etc.

Comment: Ever tried with `copy "the end *.txt" "the end all.txt"` etc.?

Comment: (Ever tried with copy "the end *.txt" "the end all.txt" etc.? – aschipfl) -> this is just an example of what I want. I have 10000 files in the folder.

Comment: @oneonezero, did aschipfl's example answer work with the example you provided? You cannot expect the script to guess which files you're wanting to merge with which. You need to specify that in your script unless you wish only to match based on the first _n_ words or to auto match on everything from and including the last space character of the file name. In both those scenario's you'd be to be certain that only files which can have that required format are processed too. Given that and my last comment, do you really think that you've provided sufficient information in your question?

Answer (score 0):

This code assumes that the filenames end with SPACE then DIGITS then '.txt'. If not, it will probably not do what you want. When you believe the files will be concatenated correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Add-Content` cmdlet.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Filter '*.txt' |
    ForEach-Object {
        if ($_ -match '(.*)\d+\.txt$') {
            $newname = $_.DirectoryName + '\' + $matches[1] + 'all.txt'
            Add-Content -Path $newname -Value (Get-Content $_) -WhatIf
        }
    }
```

If you must run this from a cmd.exe shell, put the code into a file such as `doit.ps1`, then run it at the command line or in your .bat file with:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File doit.ps1
```